# How sizeof operator works for a structure

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I am reading K&R. In an example it defines an array of  structures as:

```
struct key {
char * word;
int count;
} keytab[] = {
   "auto", 0,
   "break", 0,
   /*more members*/
   "while", 0
};
```

Then to calculate the size of the array, it uses two approaches:

```
1) #define NKEYS (sizeof keytab/ sizeof(struct key))
2) #define NKEYS (sizeof keytab/ sizeof keytab[0])
```

Then it says that the second approach has the advantage that it does not need to be changed if the type changes. Can someone tell me the meaning of this last line? What advantage is being talked about here?

Comment: for `struct key` is a declaration and `keytab` is a definition. Declarations are rather type dependent. A definition (eg. `keytab`) is showing how much memory it's going to occupy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If in future you change the `keytab` array to be of a different type than `struct key`, then the first sizeof line has to be changed because the type was written there explicitly. The second sizeof line will remain working because it does not name the type, but takes whatever type of the array element is.

Answer (score 2):

> "**Can someone tell me the meaning of this last line?**"

It's quite simple really. When you declare an array of something (anything), each element is the `sizeof` that type. (e.g. `int array[10] = {0};` declares and initializes a 10-element array of `int`) Each element of the array has `sizeof (int)`.

You can access each element with `array[x]` (where x is `0-9`). Any element, e.g. `array[0]` is an `int`. (just as `*array` is a reference to the first element -- where `array[0]` is simply `*(array + 0)` in pointer notation, which, of course, is just `*(array)` or `*array`, since the parenthesis are then unnecessary).

Back to the size of the array of `struct`. `sizeof keytab` gives the total number of bytes in the array. `sizeof keytab[0]` gives the number of bytes in each element. Therefore `sizeof keytab / sizeof keytab[0]` is the number of element in the array. It is the same as writing `sizeof keytab / sizeof *keytab` or `sizeof keytab / sizeof (struct key)`.

Why? Because `sizeof keytab[0]` is just the `sizeof (struct key)`. But if you size the number of elements based on `sizeof (struct key)` and then change the type, all your code with `sizeof (struct key)` will be wrong, but if you size with `sizeof keytab[0]`, your code will continue to have the correct number of elements calculated because you calculate based on the `sizeof "an element"` not `sizeof (an arbitrary type name)`.

Comment: I think the acctual question was what the advantage is.

Comment: so why is the latter, `sizeof(keytab[0])` better?

Comment: @Yunnosch "**Can someone tell me the meaning of this last line?**" Thanks guys.

Comment: "What advantage is being talked about here?" seems to indicate that not the last code line is meant but the prose line afterwards. My interpretation is that both question marks make semantically a single question. Since it is an interpretation I did not downvote by the way.

Comment: This is hilarious. Answer the first of two questions, get downvoted. Answer the second and don't get downvoted. A good lesson, I guess. :/ (+1 from me)

Answer (score 2):

With 1) the code needs to assume that we are looking at an array of members of type `struct key`.
With 2) the code does not need to know that.

For maintainability reasons, this is considered an advantage of 2).
Consider several people working on the project, one changes the definition of the array to

```
struct key2 {    
    char * word;
    int count;
    int coolness;    
} keytab[] = /* ... */
```

and separates the definition of `struct key` elsewhere, identically to your code. The other one is in charge of the code part with the size macro definition.

Then 1) becomes wrong, but 2) stays correct.
Hence 1) would required additional synchronisation between two developers, which means additional effort and risk of errors.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone tell me the meaning of this last line?

Getting the actual number of array elements with type `struct key`

> What advantage is being talked about here?

Aside from the advantage of not being explicitly dependent to a certain type,

compilers can do more optimization for macros using actual definitions. `sizeof(var)` is much better optimized compared to `sizeof(type)`.

Comment: "`sizeof(var)` is much better optimized compared to `sizeof(type)`." Do you have any reference for your claim? The code should be identical.